How to do analysis of correlation from multiple-timepoints measurements?
My case is analyzing the association between the concentration of HIV DNA prior to therapy (time point 0, $t_0$) and the concentrations of biomarkers of HIV infection after therapy, measured in 6 time points with an interval of 6 months between each time point (e.g. $t_6$, $t_{12}$, etc.).
Research question: is there a relationship between the concentration of HIV DNA prior to therapy and the longitudinal expressions of immune activation markers during antiretroviral therapy (ART)?
Study design:

Sampling:

I have had feedbacks:

Analyzing a dependent variable collected in multiple time points by repeated measures ANOVA.
Analyzing the correlation to explain causality of the independent variable (collected in $t_0$) and the dependent variable (collected in $t_6$, $t_{12}$, $t_{18}$, $t_{24}$, $t_{30}$, $t_{36}$) using linear regression.

The question: What would you suggest to analyze the outcomes of the measurements, particularly to explain whether the concentration of HIV DNA prior to therapy is a predictor of biomarker expressions after therapy?

If one is interested in the overall trend over time, then a simple linear regression will do, particularly given you have evenly spaced time units. Because we are dealing with time, particularly over a long time course, there may be nonlinearities present (it's likely for example that the effects "taper off" over time). It would be good then to plot your data first to see how your DV changes with time, then depending on the data you can fit accordingly (where in the case of nonlinear trends you may have to incorporate polynomials or splines to handle the job).
I will note that temporal variables do not imply strict causality. There are any number of other confounding factors that may crop up as a result of how things change with time, so one should consider those extraneous variables when running and reporting this analysis. I would just be careful about how strongly worded the term "causality" is used here if this is for a published paper.

Hi Shawn, thank you so much for the insights! I am sorry it has taken me quite some time, but I studied it again and also consulted some of my friends. One of the most potential solutions that I might take is the general linear model (GLM) approach.

With the GLM itself being a linear regression analysis as well; you're spot on, first I need to check on how the DV changes with time. I understand your caution on causality. That's correct, I think I won't be able to infer a causal relationship at this stage. Maybe later, with an improved study design and more information to analyze. Thanks a bunch! - Nawang -
